# PHP Sessions expire too soon

Tags: php, session

I'm running a website with a nginx server with PHP Fastcgi on a VPS. I tried to configure the php.ini (in /etc/php5/cgi) to have PHP session last longer than 3 days (259200 seconds), but it didn't work and my php sessions don't last more than one hour.

My current session config in the php.ini:

```
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 259200
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 259200
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 259200
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
```

What may be the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure that's the php.ini file being loaded into PHP? Have you tried double checking the "Loaded Configuration File" path in `phpinfo()` to make sure?

Comment: Try using `var_dump(ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime'));` in a PHP file across all the applicable settings in your PHP ini values to ensure that they are not being overridden somewhere else.

Comment: @animuson: Yes, it's being loaded. Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /etc/php5/cgi
Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed  /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/curl.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/gd.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini

Comment: @Treffynnon: string(6) "259200"

Comment: What's your fastcgi cache validity duration?

Comment: @favoretti: How can I check that?

Comment: @NeDark: either in nginx.conf or in your_site.conf, do you have anything like:  fastcgi_cache_valid     200 1m;  ?

Comment: @favoretti: No, i don't have anything like that

Comment: @NeDark: peculiar really. I read somewhere at some point that nginx doesn't honor php.ini's session.* parameters, but I can't find off-hand how to increase PHP's session validity via nginx. Good one really :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds a bit like Ubuntu or Debian on the server. If I rememeber correctly there is a cronjob somewhere (installed either by the php5 or the php5-common package) which cleans out your session directory more often.

I'd recommend you configure your sessions to be saved somewhere else (than the default). Adjust `session.save_path` and verify to cronjob doesn't empty it.

The cronjob is somewhere like `/etc/cron.d/php` - to be certain, run `dpkg -L php5` or `dpkg -L php5-common`. Assuming you are on Ubuntu (or Debian) this should show you the location of all installed files.

Comment: Finally I solved the problem by [storing sessions with memcached](http://www.dotdeb.org/2008/08/25/storing-your-php-sessions-using-memcached/). However, your solution looks to be valid so I'll acept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To help you debug, you can check the current setting that the PHP cron job is "seeing" by executing:

/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

The maxlifetime script searches all your php.ini files for the session.gc_maxlifetime and uses the largest value.
The value printed is in minutes.

Comment: I guess this is the script in ubuntu 15.10: /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean